# How to convert PostgreSQL query to Linq to SQL for NHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I am using NHibernate and LINQ to SQL and I want to convert the following SQL query:

```
select min(T."CustomerName") from public."Jobs" as T group by lower(T."CustomerName");
```

I want to convert it in LINQ to SQL and add it in a DAO.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have found the answer.

Here it is:

```
return HibernateTemplate.Execute(session => (from r in session.Query<Job>()
                                             group r by r.CustomerName.ToLower()
                                             into g
                                             let c = g.Min(l => l.CustomerName)
                                             orderby c
                                             select c)).ToList();
```

Thank you people.